# Netbeans PHP throws 404 not found

Tags: php, apache, netbeans, mamp

Hey everyone, I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to setup a project locally with Netbeans on mac. I have used MAMP to setup my apache server and I test it and the server is running. However when trying to run my simple hello world PHP project I get a 404 not found:

Current URL used for project: `http:/localhost/PhpProject1/index.php`

> Error: The requested URL `/PhpProject1/index.php` was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

**My project is found under:** `/Applications/MAMP/dtdocs/PhpProject1/`

Dir Tree for www: MAMP>htdocs>PhpProject1>index.php

Comment: Show your dir structure to the www folder.

Comment: Try `http://localhost/htdocs/PhpProject1/index.php`

Comment: Thanks, i just tried this ^^ and still gives the 404. I dont understand because i can see the file is there, and i have also set RW permissions to the entire folder to be sure.

Comment: @user1515668 are you sure that you have started Apache ? Otherwise try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: I owe you a beer my friend, by switching localhost with 127.0.0.1 it works. Why is this? MAMP specifies that you should use localhost when referring to the dtdocs folder?

Comment: @Staleyr i have no idea, you may take a look [here](http://serverfault.com/a/76212)

Comment: Maybe MAC treats "localhost" differently to Windows and Linux?

Comment: `localhost` might resolve to your local IPv6 address (I'm not a Mac user but perhaps the `ping localhost` command can clarify that). If Apache is listening to IPv4 address then you'll get no matches. I can't see though what your IDE has to do with the question.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this issue, here is how I solved it in Xampp:

Create your folder in **htdoc**

`C:\xampp\htdocs\FolderName\phpfile.php`

To run this file the URL will be set as:

`http://localhost/FolderName/phpfile.php`

That's it.. Enjoy :)